# How to add an html variable to django form

Tags: python, html, django-forms

I am currently making an ecommerce website using django however i have come across a problem that i havent been able to solve, i want to add a "max" value to a form field that is linked to each products stock quantity. however since the for loop is in the html itself i cant seem to get it to apply, even using django_widget_attributes.

This is my form:

```
class CartAddProductForm(forms.Form):

quantity = forms.IntegerField(
    min_value=1,
    widget=NumberInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control text-center px-3',
        'value': 1,
    })
)
```

And this is where i render it inside a for loop to get each product in the cart:

```
<div class="col-6 col-sm-5 col-lg-2 align-self-center">
            <form method="post" action="{% url 'cart:cart_add' product.id %}">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <span class="input-group shopping-cart">
                    {% render_field item.update_quantity_form.quantity max='{{ product.stock }}' %}
                    <input type="hidden" name="overwrite_qty" value="True">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <button class="btn" type="submit" title="update">
                            <i class="bi bi-bag-plus-fill"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </span>
           </form>
       </div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. And i'm sorry if this is simple, but i haven't found any resources discussing it.

Comment: You don't need braces here, it should be just `max=product.stock`.

Comment: @SUTerliakov This worked perfectly, i added a space the first time and it didnt work but this was the solution. Thank you so much.